# Internal`WithTimeStamps usage

Tags: undocumented

I was digging inside the `Iconize` implementation a little bit and saw that there's a function `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad `` which loads the `FormatValues` for objects.

For the most part it's boring, but one interesting function that I saw in it was `` Internal`WithTimeStamps ``. A sample usage of `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad `` is:

```
BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad[MakeBoxes, 
 IconizedObject["asd"], 
 StandardForm, 
 "NotebookTools`Iconize`", 
 {{IconizedObject, _}},
 Hold[IconizedObject]
 ]
```

And tracking the `WithTimeStamps` call inside we see it's running:

```
Internal`WithTimestampsPreserved[
 {IconizedObject},
 Apply[
  (BoxForm`wasProtected = Unprotect[#1];
    (* Uninteresting Which block removed *);
    Protect[Evaluate[BoxForm`wasProtected]]) &,
  {{IconizedObject, _}},
  {1}
  ];
 DumpGet[System`Private`$SystemFileDir <> 
   System`Dump`fixfile["NotebookTools`Iconize`"] <> "x"];
 ]
```

Running this seems to do nothing interesting so I'm wondering why it exists and in what way there are "Timestamps" in the call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an internal and undocumented function that can be used to prevent reevaluation of expressions whenever particular symbols contained in them change. This is a simple example:

```
Clear[a, b];
b = 1 + a

(* 1 + a *)

Internal`WithTimestampsPreserved[{a}, a = 1];
{a, b}

(* {1, 1 + a} *)
```

Although the value of `a` changed, the evaluator did not think that `b` might need reevaluation.

That is because we preserved the timestamp of `a`, i.e. forced it to remain the same.

Contrast with the normal behavior where updating `a` also changed its timestamp, so now `b` is out of date and must be reevaluated.

```
a = 1; {a, b}

(* {1, 2} *)
```

In some sense, it accomplishes the opposite of [`Update`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update.html), which can be used to force reevaluation in certain situations.

Comment: This example makes me a little confused about the standard evaluation process.  I thought the evaluation of `b` would occur when it is called, which means it should have returned `2` regardless of whether `WithTimestampPreserved` was used to modify `a`.  This answer seems to suggest that under normal conditions, `b` is actually updated when `a` is modified (and not when `WithTimestampPreserved` is used).  Does that mean all symbols and definitions are normally updated each time a symbol definition is modified?

Comment: No, b is updated when it is evaluated.  But to avoid needless and potentially expensive reevaluations, when b evaluates, it checks whether a has changed since they last time it was evaluated.  Since a hasn't (due to WithTimestampsPreserved), b uses the cached value it has from its previous evaluation, which is that a stays a.  You can see this by alternately inserting `Update[Unevaluated @ a]` and `Update[Unevaluated @ b]` betwee WithTimeStampsPreserved and `{a,b}`.  As always, internal, undocumented functions are not supported and may clean your drive, kill your pets, or do other bad things.

Comment: Exactly, the timestamps are used as a low-level optimization in the evaluator: there is no need to to do a full reevaluation of an expression if none of its parts have changed.