# Is there a good reason that there is no UnIconize?

Tags: input-forms, iconize

Consider the following:

```
tmpExpr = {1 a, 2 a, 3 a, 4 a} (*here a proxy for possibly a very long list*);
tmpIcon = Iconize[tmp, "my list"]
```

I think it would be useful if

```
Select[tmpIcon/.a->3, EvenQ]
```

would return the same thing as

```
Select[tmpExpr/.a->3, EvenQ]
```

Instead, one must do

```
Select[First[tmpIcon] /. a -> 3, EvenQ]
```

and this solution might be difficult for beginners to find.

Wouldn't it make sense to have an `UnIconize[a_IconizedObject]` that does effectively the same thing so that casual users can find it?

Would there be a fundamental problem to have an IconizedObject evaluate to its first argument for `Evaluate[IconizedObject]`?

Comment: in your second line of code `tmp` should be `tmpExpr`

Comment: This isn’t the way that iconized objects are meant to be used I think.  When you write tmpIcon=Iconize[tmp, "my list"], you are supposed to highlight the Iconize expression and evaluate it in place, creating the icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use Iconize object assigned to a variable (Mathematica 11.3)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/168051/how-use-iconize-object-assigned-to-a-variable-mathematica-11-3)

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks. I agree that it was probably not the intention that they be used that way (I did see Szbloc's post).  The question is why not have an UnIconize. I think there are plausibly useful use cases, making one up here:
sol = Iconize[Solve[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d == 0,x],"roots of polynomial"];
values = Function[{a,b,c,d},x/.UnIconize[sol]]

Comment: @CraigCarter -  in your example, what is the purpose of using `Iconize`? What does it add?

Comment: @JasonB. It has the advantage of things looking tidier perhaps. Isn’t that the main point of Iconize?

Comment: It is tidier only if you use the output icon itself in an input somewhere. The icon evaluates as the list. ```tmpIcon``` is not the icon and does not represent the list, but the list can be extracted from it with First.

Comment: The kernel version of `UnIconize` seems to be `First`: try `First[tmpIcon]`. Does that accomplish what you want?

Comment: By the way, "Possible Issues" under Iconize spells out the difference between the output icon and the result of the evaluation creating the icon.

Answer (score 5):

Normally we don't like code images posted on this site, but I think in this case we should allow it, so I'm going ahead. Consider the following.

[image: code]

Clicking on **Uniconize** in the drop-down list, will give the following expression:

```
Select[{a, 2 a, 3 a, 4 a} /. a -> 3, EvenQ]
```

So `Uniconize` exists as a front-end command, but not as a system function. It can also be accessed by choosing **Un/Iconize Selection** from the **Edit** menu. I believe that the Wolfram developers see no compelling use for an `Uniconize` kernel function. With `Iconize`, it is different. `Iconize` can take up to two arguments and a Method option (for indicating a compression method), so it needs to be implemented as a kernel function

You should also be aware that ref/Iconize >  Properties & Relations discusses thus issue.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. I am thinking of the case where you *wouldn’t want* to see the list—in a non-artificial scenario, the list could be several screens full of an expression.   For example, the Solve case in the comments above. The question isn’t about how to do it, it is a question about why something is missing that I think is potentially useful for beginners.

Comment: @CraigCarter I think it comes down to the design of the function - you aren't meant to write `var = Iconize[...]`, no kernel variable in normal use should be set that way.  Iconize is meant to store expressions in a notebook.  So if you did a long computation and want the results in the notebook but don't want to look at them, do something like `var = Solve[...]; Iconize[var, "solve result"]`  So the kernel still knows that `var` is the useful thing, and the notebook has a copyable and usable version of the result.

Comment: @CraigCarter. "I am thinking of the case where you wouldn’t want to see the list". `Iconize` handles that case beautifully — you just evaluate the `Iconize` expression in place. Now you have you giant expression shrunk down to where it takes up vyery little screen space but it is still easily accessed any time you want it

Comment: @JasonB. Would you say that `Iconize` is similar to `MatrixForm`, in that it is a wrapper that affects display, which can be copied and used as input in the FE; however, when stored in a kernel variable, it no longer represents the data it wraps? (Or words to that effect.)

Comment: I don't use `MatrixForm` very often myself, but what you describe sounds like a good comparison.